# How to manually ack messages from rabbitmq using spring integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-amqp

[EDIT] Uploading complete configs:

**rabbit.xml which dequeues from rabbit**

```
<rabbit:connection-factory id="amqpConnectionFactoryInbound" 
host="${rabbit.host}" port="${rabbit.port}"
username="${rabbit.username}" password="${rabbit.password}" channel-
cache-size="5"
connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactoryInbound"/>

<beans:bean id="rabbitConnectionFactoryInbound" 
class="com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory">
<beans:property name="requestedHeartbeat" 
value="60" />
</beans:bean>


<!-- Inbound Adapter to AMQP RabbitMq and write to file -->
<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter id="rabbitMQInboundChannelAdapter" 
channel="rabbitInboundMessageChannel"
concurrent-consumers="8" task-
executor="rabbit-executor" connection-
factory="amqpConnectionFactoryInbound"
message-converter="byteArrayToStringConverter" queue-
names="${rabbit.queue}" acknowledge-mode="MANUAL" error-
channel="errorChannelId"
prefetch-count="25" />

<header-enricher input-channel="rabbitInboundMessageChannel" output-
channel="rabbitOutboundboundMessageChannel">
<int:header name="Operation" value="${operation.rabbit}" />
<int:header name="GUID" expression="#{ 
'T(java.util.UUID).randomUUID().toString()' }" />
<int:header name="operationStartTime" expression="#{ 
'T(java.lang.System).currentTimeMillis()' }" />
</header-enricher>

<int:channel id="rabbitOutboundboundMessageChannel">
<int:interceptors>
<int:wire-tap channel="loggerChannel" />
</int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<task:executor id="rabbit-executor" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS" 
pool-size="10-30"
queue-capacity="25" />
</beans:beans>
```

**The message is then sent to router channel: router.xml**

```
<int:header-enricher input-channel="rabbitOutboundboundMessageChannel" 
output-channel="routerChannel">
<int:header name="Operation" value="${operation.router}" 
overwrite="true" />
<int:header name="file_name" expression="headers['GUID'] + '.xml'" />
<int:header name="operationStartTime" expression="#{ 
'T(java.lang.System).currentTimeMillis()' }"
overwrite="true" />
<int:error-channel ref="errorChannelId" />
</int:header-enricher>

<int:recipient-list-router id="rabbitMsgrouter" input-
channel="routerChannel">
<int:recipient channel="fileBackupChannel" selector-expression="new 
String(payload).length()>0" />
<int:recipient channel="transformerChannel" />
</int:recipient-list-router>

<int:channel id="transformerChannel">
<int:interceptors>
<int:wire-tap channel="loggerChannel" />
</int:interceptors>
</int:channel>
<int:channel id="fileBackupChannel"/>
<int:channel id="loggerChannel"/>
</beans>
```

**The message is now sent to persister.xml and transformer.xml. The following is persister.xml and I want to ack if persistence is successful. There are other downstream processes after transformer.xml**

```
<int:header-enricher input-channel="fileBackupChannel" output-
channel="fileSaveChannel">
<int:header name="Operation" value="${operation.filePersister}" 
overwrite="true" />
<int:header name="replyChannel" value="nullChannel" />
<int:header name="operationStartTime" expression="#{ 
'T(java.lang.System).currentTimeMillis()' }" />
<int:error-channel ref="errorChannelId" />
</int:header-enricher>

<int-file:outbound-gateway id="fileBackUpChannelAdapter" 
directory="${file.location}"
request-channel="fileSaveChannel" reply-channel="rabbitAckChannel"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="rabbitAckChannel" output-
channel="nullChannel" ref="ackRabbit" method="handleRabbitAcks" />

<bean id="ackRabbit" 
class="com.expedia.dataloader.rabbit.RabbitAcknowledgement"/>

<int:channel id="rabbitAckChannel">
<int:interceptors>
<int:wire-tap channel="loggerChannel" />
</int:interceptors>
</int:channel>
<int:channel id="loggerChannel"/>
<int:channel id="fileSaveChannel"/>
</beans>
```

I'm having trouble manually acking payloads from rabbitmq.

This is my work flow:

**1. Get message from rabbit using inbound-channel-adapter:**

```
<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter id="rabbitMQInboundChannelAdapter" 
channel="rabbitInboundMessageChannel"
concurrent-consumers="${rabbit.concurrentConsumers}" task-
executor="rabbit-executor" connection-
factory="amqpConnectionFactoryInbound"
message-converter="byteArrayToStringConverter" queue-
names="${rabbit.queue}" acknowledge-mode="MANUAL" error-
channel="errorChannelId"
prefetch-count="${rabbit.prefetchCount}" />
```

**2. Persist message to disk using outbound-gateway:**

```
<int-file:outbound-gateway id="fileBackUpChannelAdapter" 
directory="${file.location}"
request-channel="fileSaveChannel" reply-channel="loggerChannel" />
```

**3. ack from rabbit when persister (step 2) succeeds.**

for step (3), i wrote the following code:

```
public class RabbitAcknowledgement {
public void handleRabbitAcks(Message<?> message) throws IOException {
com.rabbitmq.client.Channel channel = (Channel) 
message.getHeaders().get("amqp_channel");
long deliveryTag = (long) message.getHeaders().get("amqp_deliveryTag");
channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, false);
}
```

which I'm calling from spring via:

```
<int:service-activator input-
channel="rabbitOutboundboundMessageChannel" output-
channel="routerChannel" ref="ackRabbit" method="handleRabbitAcks" />
```

This doesn't work and the the rabbit payloads in my queue are not acked.

My questions are:

1. Do I need MANUAL ack in this scenario?
2. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are symptoms proving not work, please?

Comment: The payloads remain on rabbit and are not consumed by the consumers.

Comment: Also, in my current setup, I believe I ack 1 message per thread. Can I somehow increase the rate (I.e acknowledge in batches?) not critical to feature but was wondering if I make the system more efficient somehow

Comment: You generally don't need manual acks; with AUTO, the container will ack the message if the persistence is successful and nack it if an exception is thrown.

It's unusual to need to use manual acks for a simple scenario like this.

However, it should work.

Are you running the ack on the container thread? Or are you handing off to another thread using a queue or executor channel?

Can you edit the question to show your complete configuration (including channels).

Also turn on DEBUG logging to see if it provides any more information.

Comment: Thanks Gary. How would AUTO work if there are other downstream processes running on the same thread? For eg. after persistence, i want to transform the payload and write to solr. currently the ACK happens only when both transformation and solr succeeds causing a lot of load on the rabbit server. All these processes have their own configs (rabbit.xml, persist.xml, transform.xml, solr.xml etc.).

Comment: @GaryRussell I have edited the question with the complete config.

Comment: I don't see any edits; yes, in that case, the ack will happen when everything is done; you would use manual acks if you want to ack before the solr stuff. However, since your `handleRabbitAcks` returns void; I don't see how any more work can be done after it is called.

Comment: @GaryRussell I apologize. you should be able to see the edits now.

Comment: there is a router which sends the message to persister and transformer. persister is the end of that flow but transformer continues to other operations and solr. I wanted to ack after persister and let transformation continue with the original payload. Hence handleRabbitAcks is void. Hope my explanation makes sense. I have uploaded the 3 configs in the edit.

Comment: @GaryRussell Manual acking seems slower than auto ack with the same load. Is the class and method for manual acking the bottle neck here? Any tips on improving the acknowledgement rate would be very helpful. The consumer utilization is just 2% with this change

Comment: I can't imagine why there would be much difference for your use case. What do you mean by "slower"? I can't see that the listener Vs. the container calling `basicAck()` would make any difference. Perhaps you need to increase the `prefetchCount` but, again, who does the acks shouldn't make a difference. If you use AUTO ack mode and increase the `txSize`, the container will only send an ack every `txSize` messages (but will increase the possibility of redeliveries).

Comment: @GaryRussell I ran a performance test for the older setup (ack after write to solr using AUTO ack) and the newer setup (use MANUAL ack and then write to solr). The delivery or acknowledgement rate is much lower for MANUAL acks compared to AUTO acks (2X difference)

Comment: Something else must have changed; I can't imagine moving the `basicAck` to earlier would make much difference; in fact, with the default prefetch (1), the next message is likely to be available sooner. I suggest you re-examine your changes.

Answer (score 2):

It should work fine; I just ran a quick test and it works for me...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So44666444Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So44666444Application.class, args).close();
    }

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate template;

    private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        this.template.convertAndSend("foo", "bar");
        latch.await();
    }

    @Bean
    public AmqpInboundChannelAdapter adapter(ConnectionFactory cf) {
        AmqpInboundChannelAdapter adapter = new AmqpInboundChannelAdapter(listenerContainer(cf));
        adapter.setOutputChannelName("ack");
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public AbstractMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer(ConnectionFactory cf) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(cf);
        container.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL);
        container.setQueueNames("foo");
        return container;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "ack")
    public void ack(@Header(AmqpHeaders.CHANNEL) Channel channel, @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) Long tag)
            throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Acking: " + tag);
        channel.basicAck(tag, false);
        latch.countDown();
    }

}
```

If I set a breakpoint on the `basicAck`, I see the message as unacked on the console; stepping over to the next line and the message is removed.

Comment: Thanks @Gary Russell I found a bug in my code and got it to work: Uploaded the working config to the original post. Is there any way I can make this more efficient? (ack faster, use less resources etc.)